# User_data of aws_instance not executed at launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, user-data

I'm trying to pass some post deployment configuration on an AWS instance used as a gitlab runner but the script is not executed. No errors shown after applying the script. Any ideas where the issue is from ?

```
  resource "aws_instance" "gitlab-runner" {
  ami                         = "ami-09e67e426f25ce0d7"
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  user_data                   = file("gitlab-runner-startupscript.sh")
  key_name                    = aws_key_pair.gitlab_runner_key.key_name
  security_groups             = ["${aws_security_group.exposed-ssh.id}"]
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.gitlab_subnet.id
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
}
```

I also tried passing the script directly without using a file and it still dont work:

```
   user_data = <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
touch yayitworks
EOF
```

Comment: So your enter `gitlab-runner-startupscript.sh` is just the two lines of code?

Comment: Also did you check logs in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`?

Comment: @Marcin for the sake of the example I only pasted the sanity check line.

Comment: What about `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`? If you can't provide your full code, its rather difficult to specualte what it does not work.

Comment: @Marcin thanks for the advice, the logs stop at a certain command which is exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1ls. I'll check what is causing that

Comment: Sure. Let me know how it will go, so I can provide an answer.

Comment: I dont know why, but the script stops at this command `sudo useradd --comment 'GitLab Runner' --create-home gitlab-runner --shell /bin/bash`. I had to do a work around, by uploading the script first to S3 and calling it using aws s3 cp command and execut it using `sudo bash script.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource block looks good. I tried it in my setup, but with a different ami.

Please ensure you are looking for the file yayitworks in root directory (/)

```sh
cd /;ls -lrt
```

Comment: yes it's there. Thanks for your answer? there is a problem with my bash script. I'll check what's causing the issue